# Preamplifier to get Max Output Voltage

Tags: microphone, audio, line-level

I'm looking a preamplifier to get 1-2 Volt as Maximum Output Voltage of a microphone with jack or RCA.

To get a line-in signal and then modulate in FM. I don't know if this I've found works.

[Beh­ringer MA400](https://www.thomann.de/es/behringer_ma_400.htm?glp=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiA0b_QBRCeARIsAFntQ9qKqxsLdbmJCPvAnOreQln6HexcD-QzMCDxQJEZ5sBQUKRem5o69B4aAo74EALw_wcB)

Because to modulate in FM I need to know exactly the Maximum Output Voltage the microphone line-level can get.

max|x(t)|

If i can regulate the output would be perfect.

Do you know a product or something like I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mic and line levels are pretty standard, so any mic pre-amp should do the job. Some do it better than others, some have less inherent noise, some have different connections, some are parts of complete audio interfaces or even mixers.

Now, there are 2 (if not more) ways of dealing with the maximum level. Either using a brick wall limiter between the mic pre-amp and the FM transmitter, or you do it yourself using a level meter and lowering the gain when you notice the signal getting too 'hot'.

If you need to be absolutely sure, use a limiter. If you want the cheapest option, do it yourself. Just make sure you pick a mic pre-amp that displays the output level clearly if you choose to control the level yourself.

The one you linked to won't work. It's a headphone amplifier, meant to drive low impedance loads (headphones). Look in [this category](https://www.thomann.de/es/preamps.html) instead if you want something similar.

Oh, I also noticed that some have phono input but a RIAA EQ. Don't pick those just to have a phono input, they are for (vinyl) record players.